# How can linear-types replace monads?

Tags: types, monads, type-theory, linear-types

I was doing some research into linear types and came across [this comment on HN](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2311445). Specifically, it says that in

> (Clean, ATS, etc ...), linear types are used to encode side-effects,
>   as an alternative to monads.

What does this mean? How are linear types a replacement for monads?

Comment: If there is no other reference to an object then it can be modified safely. Hence in this case no need for the ST monad. I guess it is just that, it does not replace monad generally.

Comment: Same for `IO` where you pass around a `TheRealWorld` token which cannot be duplicated and entails a sequential order of evaluation.